# jQuery-ui autocomplete working locally but not on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, heroku

I'm having trouble getting my JQuery-ui autocomplete work on production (heroku, rails), but it works locally.

Here is my javascript (yes i know it's messy, it's my first time using jquery-ui)

```
<script>
$(function() {
var projects = '/courses.json'

$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: projects,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.course.abbrev );
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      window.location.replace("/courses/"+ui.item.id);
        return false;
    }
})
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.abbrev + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure but this may be the problem:

"/courses.json"

works correctly and lists all of my objects in JSON format

However,

"/courses.json?term=m"

returns the correct array of objects locally, but remotely just returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

If you are quering a remote server make sure You use JSONP instead of JSON in your jQuery AJAX request.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I just added my javascript code... I don't think I have any ajax requests (well I don't know too much about them). Do I have to use a different method call for obtaining the JSON information?

Comment: Sorry for not providing it earlier, can I change my autocomplete to use an AJAX call to get it to work? how?